# Joins on Ignited Datatables

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I was using the standard DataTables setup but, ran into problems with JOINS. Started using the script here: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/22964#Comment_22964 and my JOINS work fine now. Thing is I`m having problems converting some of my old code to work with this version.

In the standard version I used the following to convert the dates from yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy but, cannot get it working:

```
        "aoColumns" : [
        {"bVisible": false, "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false},      
        {"aaSorting": [[2,'desc']], "fnRender": format_ddmmyyyy},
        null, 
        null,
        null,
                null,
        {"bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false},
        {"bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false},
        {"bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false}]
      });
});



// Take date from mysql, formatted yyyy-mm-dd, and return as dd/mm/yyyy
function format_ddmmyyyy(oObj) {
  var sValue = oObj.aData[oObj.iDataColumn]; 
  var aDate = sValue.split('-');
  return aDate[2] + "/" + aDate[1] + "/" + aDate[0];
}
```

Also I had this code to create a new column and get the 'leads.lead_id' and call an ajax file.

```
    $row[] = "<span style='cursor:pointer'><img src='../images/more-info.png'         alt='more info' onClick='javascript:my_onclick({$row[0]});'/></span>";

 /*  on click get lead_id */
  function my_onclick(data)
{
    $("#content").slideUp(5);
    showLoading();
    $.post("ajax/pending-client-details.php",
    {'lead_id': data},
        function(data)
        {
        $("#content").html(data).slideDown("slow");
        hideLoading();

    }

);
```

I tried this but, it does not collect the 'leads.lead_id'

```
->add_column('moreinfo', '<span style="cursor:pointer"><img src="../images/more-> > info.png" alt="more info" onClick="javascript:my_onclick($1);"/></span>', 'leads.lead_id')
```

Any kind of help would be great!

Comment: have managed to get the ajax calling sorted out but, still a little stuck creating a function for the date convert.

Comment: '->edit_column('date_time', '$1', 'callback_test(leads.lead_id, date_time)')'

Comment: function test($id, $date) {
  $date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($yourtimestring));
  return $date . '_' . $id; // whatever you want..
}

Answer (score 0):

had this in the wrong place:

> {"aaSorting": [[2,'desc']], "fnRender": format_ddmmyyyy}